# column manipulation with different files

Tags: awk, formatting

I have a really annoying problem: I have 2 files that I am using, and I need to replace the columns of the original file while keeping its formatting intact. This is the format:

> HETATM    1 CA   LIG     1      38.925  -1.038 -22.754  1.00  0.00          Ca
>   HETATM    2 CA   LIG     1      38.509  -0.159 -22.703  1.00  0.00          Ca
>   HETATM    3 CA   LIG     1      37.873  -0.673 -22.309  1.00  0.00          Ca
>   HETATM    4 CA   LIG     1      37.261  -1.434 -22.569  1.00  0.00          Ca
>   HETATM    5 CA   LIG     1      37.800  -2.277 -22.363  1.00  0.00          Ca
>   HETATM    6 CA   LIG     1      37.764  -1.612 -21.664  1.00  0.00          Ca
>   HETATM    7 CA   LIG     1      36.833  -1.557 -21.515  1.00  0.00          Ca
>   HETATM    8 CA   LIG     1      35.941  -1.643 -21.936  1.00  0.00          Ca
>   HETATM    9 CA   LIG     1      35.959  -2.319 -22.634  1.00  0.00          Ca
>   HETATM   10 CA   LIG     1      36.670  -2.501 -21.971  1.00  0.00          Ca

Here is what it *should* look like, but, upon any manipulation, this formatting is lost.

[image: This is what the format should look like actually, instead of just a block of text...]

So, now I have a different file in .xyz format, and I need to substitute column 9 (1.00) from the above-mentioned file with the column $6 from the .xyz file.

> `10
>
>   CA 38.6675 -1.72133 -22.1513 6.90816 3.5
>   CA 38.925 -1.03771 -22.7538 6.87802 4
>   CA 38.5086 -0.158653 -22.7027 6.12023 3.5
>   CA 37.8732 -0.67308 -22.309 5.93085 3.75
>   CA 37.2605 -1.43401 -22.569 6.07069 3.25
>   CA 37.8002 -2.27692 -22.3632 6.39441 2.25
>   CA 37.7642 -1.61234 -21.6638 5.44254 3
>   CA 36.8325 -1.55711 -21.5145 5.45608 3.75
>   CA 35.9408 -1.64281 -21.936 5.20951 4
>   CA 35.9593 -2.31915 -22.6336 5.91997 4.5`

I use the following command:
`awk 'NR==FNR{c11[NR]=$6; next} {$9=c11[FNR]}1' data.xyz data.pdb > out.pdb`

I do get what I need technically, but the file is not recognised as a .pdb, and spacing is lost:

[image: this is the output after AWK...]

This is very confusing and I am not sure how to proceed. Many thanks for our help in input in advance!

Comment: read the [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and read about `FS`, `OFS` (Field Sep and Output Field Sep). Good luck.

Comment: Please use code tags for your outputs and don't show us images so that we could better understand your question and try to help you.

Comment: Thanks, i do both because i find it hard to explain how the format is different and code tags do not necessarily show it, hence the pictures...

Comment: I am not familiar with `pdb` files but if you need to align some columns I would recommend to use `column` command!

Answer (score 0):

## Answer fits your files specifically

I think printf will be more suitable to print your lines:

**read** awk's printf manual

I have changed awk's `1` with awk's `printf` formatting:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{c11[NR]=$6; next} {$9=c11[FNR]} {printf "%s %2s %s %s %s %s %s %s %4s %s %s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague (poorly formatted input/output, output that doesn't match the input, no expected output, no statement of whether you want the spaces retained or new values padded to retain alignment, no indication if the spaces are blanks or tabs or both, etc.) but maybe this is what you want, using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ cat file1
a      b         c     d

$ cat file2
X Y

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next} {$0=gensub(/((\S+\s+){1})\S+/,"\\1"a[FNR],1)} 1' file2 file1
a      Y         c     d

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next} {$0=gensub(/((\S+\s+){2})\S+/,"\\1"a[FNR],1)} 1' file2 file1
a      b         Y     d

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next} {$0=gensub(/((\S+\s+){3})\S+/,"\\1"a[FNR],1)} 1' file2 file1
a      b         c     Y
```